# simulate google image search page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, load

I'm working on an online food delivery site using ASP.NET/C#, I have a page for displaying restaurant list:

http://www.zoodfood.net/Restaurant/newlist.aspx?page=1

you can see initial interface of this page in the above address, currently it displays only 6 restaurants in each page, it has a query string (page=1) which determines restaurant index to load from a database, but I'm going to simulate something like google image search page, so that there would be no need to use a query string and users would not need to change page. My users could easily scroll the page and new items are dynamically loaded

how should I implement such a technology? is there any sample or tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique your looking for is "Infinite scrolling" and there's a fairly good looking tutorial at http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/infinite-scrolling-aspnet and a [Microsoft one here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETInfiniteLoading-10c3f379)